# Setting up multiple schedules for a ResourcePool

Tags: schedule, anylogic

I am doing a simulation of a production line, which is built through Excel.
Now there is one, which needs free setting of worker shifts for each machine, three shifts in total.

My idea is to create three different Schedules, representing each of the three shifts, and then in the ResourcePool, use the If statement to set up the use of each shift. As shown in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvziq.png)

But it didn't work. If it is possable, Could you please tell me if there is something wrong with the Java statement or the idea is wrong.
If possible, could you please tell me how to set multiple schedules in ResourcePool?

Additions to the question：
The model is to do the evaluation of the production system and the shift of the workers is an important evaluation parameter. What I want to do is to enter the shift of the workers directly in the Excel sheet and ResourcePool recognizes and uses the corresponding Schedule.

I tried to generate the corresponding Schedule by code, but the Schedule of Resourcepool cannot be set dynamically. So I would like to try to manually input multiple Schedules into the model and then set the corresponding Schedule in ResourcePool by If statement like the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need multiple schedules? And what is the error you get? Please ensure we get the right info so we can help :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have read your latest blog and it is very interesting and very helpful. next time I will think more about how to ask a good question. And Mr. Vosloo  has perfectly answered my question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that the location where you placed the code is a static parameter, thus it is only evaluated once, when the object is created and not checked continuously.

This is indicated by the little popup when you hover over the button that change the entry field from code to  value

[image]

If it was dynamic it would state Dynamic Value instead of Static Value

Secondly, inside that field you must use a ternary operator, not an if statement, so that the result of the formula is a scheduled object, else you will get a "misplaced construct(s)" error

If you changed the code to

```
v_Shift == "Shift1" ? 
s_Shift1 : v_Shift == "Shift2" ? s_Shift2 : s_Shift3
```

It will work BUT:

1. It will only be evaluated when the object is created and not again
2. Rather not use `==` on Strings, always use `.equals()`, on Strings it might work, and sometimes it might not. You can do some research as to why ;-)

Solution: You will have to use a function to change the schedule of the resource pool. Call this function whenever the `v_Shift` variable changes

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Vosloo for your answer, The ternary operator solved my problem perfectly.
and the advice,that you give me, is very helpful for my future modeling journey.